# Linear Algebra matrices question.

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

Let $A,B$ be 2 square matrices of the same size. 
And the following holds true
$AB=A+B$

How do I prove that $(I-B)$ and $(I-A)$ are invertible

Comment: $I-B$ and $I-A$ are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $AB=A+B$ then $-A(I-B)=B$ and $-(I-A)B=A$ and replacing $B$ in the second equation we obtain that $$(I-A)(I-B)=I$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. Compute $(1-A)(1-B)$ where $1$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: I have computed and reached that det(I-B)*det(I-A)=detAB/detAB can I assume that A,B are invertible so this solution will work?

Comment: You cannot assume that $A,B$ are invertible. Take $A=B=0$.

Comment: Got it... Thanks!!!